# How to send header data along with form post in PHP

Tags: php

On form submit, data is sent via POST method. Along with this, how do I send authorization and other header data to this post URL?

```
<form action="https://www.example.com/foobar" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This post URL destination accepts data only when authorization headers are sent.

Comment: Do you have access to the other domain that you are attempting to send this request to?

Comment: Yes. I have access.

Comment: That's something you can't do with HTML. I presume it can be done with JavaScript and AJAX.

Comment: Why not send the authorization data as form fields?

Comment: @Robert You don't normally choose how to consume third-party APIs. And using HTTP headers for that task is quite a standard. The question that actually arises is why the API is been queried right from a regular HTML form.

Comment: have you ever heard about curl in php ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with a jquery post like this:

```
function submit(){
var settings = {
  "url": "https://www.example.com/foobar",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "token": "your token" // here you can add your token for authorization 
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": {"fname": $("#fname").val(), "lname": $("#lname").val()  } // your form data
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
}
```

Your `HTML` then should look like this::

```
  First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
  <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```